# indent body text but not blockquotes and images

Tags: html, css

I want to indent all text in the body of a document without indenting blockquotes or images.  In the style.css if I add:

```
body {
    text-indent: 2em;
}
```

The text is indented but so are the blockquotes and images.

Comment: I'm a new poster on html items.  I very well may deserve a downvote but please tell me why so I can (a) fix my question (b) avoid this in the future (c) others will learn from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`text-indent`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html) property applies to block containers only, so it does not affect images. But a block containing an image is affected and this may affect the position of an image.

You should set `text-indent` only on those blocks that you would like to have their first lines indented. Normally this means something like `p { text-indent: 1em; }`. If you want blocks other than `p` elements to be affected, too, write suitable selector list instead of the simple `p`.

Answer (score 2):

Set `text-indent: 0` on the elements you don't want to be indented. [Such](http://jsbin.com/iliwuv/1/edit).

For images you will either need to set them to `display: block` or put them in a container with `text-indent: 0`.